# Best way to integrate MoShi and Retrofit 2 in an Android Studio project

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

I would like to know what is the best way to integrate Retrofit with MoShi on my Android Studio project.

First of all, I use the moshi converter of retrofit :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'
```

I use the popular plugin "Json to Kotlin class" for the generation of my POJO :
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-

When I create a new POJO, I use the annotation "MoShi (Reflect)" :
[image]

It generate me a Pojo with fields like this one :

```
@Json(name = "image_url")
val imageUrl: String?
```

The problem is Retrofit2 seem don't like underscore in my fields name because I get null results with the underscored names.

Searching in the [Github issues](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/315), I found a solution. It work if I use this annotation :

```
@field:Json(name = "image_url")
val imageUrl: String?
```

So my questions are :

1. Using the `@field:Json` annotation is the best way to use MoShi with Retrofit ?
2. If yes, how to generate easily a Kotlin class with this annotation (using the same plugin or an other) ?

Comment: I think Moshi CodeGen is better than reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As apparent from this part of Moshi's documentation: "There’s no field naming strategy, versioning, instance creators, or long serialization policy. Instead of naming a field visibleCards and using a policy class to convert that to visible_cards, Moshi wants you to just name the field visible_cards as it appears in the JSON."

The preferred way is for you to not use the annotation, but instead name the fields the same way as in the JSON. With Kotlin you can use backticks for names that wouldn't otherwise be valid, e.g.`` val `image-url`: String? ``

Of course you wouldn't want to be working with such names in other parts of your code, and for that you should have separate objects for describing the data as it appears on the back-end, and another object for how it should appear in your application. We call those DTOs (Data-Transfer Objects.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I put underscore in the name of my fields, I'm not respecting the Camel case standard. So can we call this "clean code" if we do that ?